# What to do if "apt" does not work but "apt-get" does?

Tags: apt

I am using Ubuntu 14.

If I use `sudo apt install snpservices`, the command fails.

If I use `sudo apt-get install snpservices`, the install is perfect.

Guess I have something broken ... but what is it?

Thanks.

Some details:

(1) apt version:

```
sebas@ubu14snp:~$ sudo apt --version 
apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for i386
```

(2) Error message:

```
sebas@ubu14snp:/etc/apt$ sudo apt install snpservices 
Reading package lists... 
Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package snpservices
```

(3) Package is supposed to come from here:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list 
deb serveis.guifi.net/debian guifi/
```

(4) Package I use is `snpservices_0.2.2-9_all.deb`

Comment: Just tried from a 14.04 system and I can install snpservices using apt. What puzzles me is that you seem to be running an i386 system but the deb source only offers amd64 packages.

Comment: I think I am using "snpservices_0.2.2-9_all.deb", and it looks ok to me

Comment: Does your sources.list really only have one line, or did you shorten the output?

Comment: @SebastianStark I think you've found it. It seems like OP is running the 32-bit version of `apt` on a 64-bit system.

Comment: Please post the output of `uname -a`

Answer (score 4):

`apt install` is available starting in Ubuntu 14.04. In Ubuntu 14.04 and later it is possible to use either `apt install` or `apt-get install`.

Your apt package in 14.04 is not up to date. The latest version of apt in Ubuntu 14.04 is 1.0.1ubuntu2.17 from the **security** repository and your version of apt is apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for i386.

1. Download apt manually from the [official Ubuntu website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/apt/download).
2. Remove the existing apt package the strong way.

   ```
   sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq apt  
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Change directories to the directory where you downloaded the apt .deb file and install it.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_i386.deb
   ```

**Explanation**

```
reinst-required    
       A package marked reinst-required is broken and requires      
       reinstallation. These packages cannot be removed, unless   
       forced with option --force-remove-reinstreq.
```

Comment: `apt install` works fine on 14.04. I use it all the time.

Comment: I will repeat my question : "what does my ubuntu have broken" ?

Comment: Or I can change it to : "how do I fix my system" ?

Comment: I am glad your "apt install" works fine, mr wjandrea

Comment: ...(2/2) and the secure way to fix the discrepancies with apt not working as intended.

Comment: as was asked in a comment to your question: could you post the output of "uname -a" please?